# Retrieving the current frame number

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

What is the actionscript 3 syntax for retrieving the frame number that our object is currently in  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple:

```
this.currentFrame
```

where `this` is your object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks at the [currentFrame](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentFrame) property on MovieClip